How to duplicate panel with a variable in Grafana with InfluxDB data
In my Grafana, I retrieve data from InfluxDB.
So for example Iretrieve memory value on two computer named WIN0 and LIN1
On my Grafana dashboard, I created a variable called "host" with this query:
import "influxdata/influxdb/schema"
schema.tagValues(
    bucket: "COMPUTER",
    tag: "host"
)

The request is correct, i can see the both value WIN0 and LIN1
So in my Dashboard I created a Panel, and in this panel I putted the request below
from(bucket: "COMPUTER")
  |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "mem")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "used_percent")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["host"] == "$host")
  |> aggregateWindow(every: v.windowPeriod, fn: mean, createEmpty: false)
  |> yield(name: "mean")

In the panel configuration, I selected the parameters below:
title = $host  to display the value of the variable "host" as title
Repeat options
Repeat by variable = i select my variable "host"
repeat direction = Horizontal
max per row = 4

But every time i display only the graph for one computer WIN0 on the entire page of grafana.
What i would like to do is something like that (the 4 graph IE, SE, US, ZA)
Grafana example
I have the feeling that the problem is more in my Influx request than Grafana configuration , but i'm lost.
Thanks for your help.

Have you enabled multi-option for your variable? Have you checked both WIN0 and LIN1 in variable selection?

If you need to display more than one host, you need to change the following line in your query:
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["host"] == "$host")

to this one:
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["host"] =~ /^${host:regex}$/ )

This will let to get information on all chosen hosts. Of course, Multi-value and Include all options should be enabled for that:

If you want all hosts to be chosen by default when you open dashboard, choose them and save dashboard with Save current variable values as dashboard default checked:


This answer would be correct if goal was to display data for both hosts on same panel. As fa's as I cat tell, it is not: OP talks about panel repeat
